# Angular 6 / declare path for library in tsconfig.lib.json

Tags: angular, path, tsconfig, compiler-options, angular-library

I'm trying to configure the paths for an `Angular 6` library (I have successfully configured the paths for a previous Angular project)

Here is what is working for my previous app in the `tsconfig.json` file:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    [...]
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      "@class/*": [ "app/class/*" ],
      "@services/*": [ "app/services/*" ],
      "@views/*": [ "app/views/*" ]
    }
}
```

and then use it like for example:

```
Import { Item } from '@class/item';
```

In my new app I'm trying the same way in the `tsconfig.**lib**.json` file:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    [...]
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      "@class/*": [ "lib/class/*" ],
      "@services/*": [ "lib/services/*" ],
      "@views/*": [ "lib/views/*" ]
    }
}
```

I have tried to import a class in a component for my library like this, but it does not work (VSCode cannot find the file):

```
Import { Item } from '@class/item';
```

Note that the `import` statement in the main project is working:

```
Import { Item } from 'myLibrary';
```

Any idea of what I'm not doing well ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If no one more experienced answers try to tweak baseUrl - maybe the problem lies there

Comment: angular will use tsconfig file which is configured in angular.json architect --> build --> options --> tsconfig.json. Where VS Code uses tsconfig.json which is in bottom. You need to add paths in boths config to get both work correctly or change project to use base tsconfig.json in angular.json.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is from my above comment, if you see that this is a correct answer.

Angular will use the `tsconfig.json` file, which is configured in the `angular.json` file in `**architect --> build --> options --> tsconfig**`. Whereas `VS Code` uses the `tsconfig.json` file, which is at the bottom of the workspace. You need to add the paths in both configurations to get both of them to work correctly, or change the project to use the base `tsconfig.json` file in the `angular.json` file.

The `tsconfig.json` file has a property that extends which will take another file as base and override everything which are declared in the `tsconfig.lib.json` file. So if you have paths declared in the `tsconfig.lib.json` file, then the paths are no longer needed in the `tsconfig.json` file.

EDIT 29.7.2019
tsconfig.json

```
"baseUrl": "src",
"paths": {
  "@ProjectName1/*": ["../projects/ProjectName1/src/app/modules/*"],
  "@Projectname2/*": ["../projects/Projectname2/src/app/modules/*"],
  "@environment/*": ["environments/*"],
  "project-core": ["../dist/project/project-core"],
  "project-core/*": ["../dist/project/project-core/*"]
}
```

And currenlty I dont't have paths declared in tsconfig.app.json because it would be same as in tsconfig.json. So this is different from my earlier answer, because I have paths only in tsconfig.json.

Comment: Would you paste the paths contents of these files in your solution ?

Comment: Edited my answer to include paths example.