# Import paths in Angular library

Tags: angular, typescript

To shorten my import paths within my library I've added

```
"paths": {
  "@services": ["lib/services"]
}
```

to my `tsconfig.lib.json`. My directory structure is mostly default, with having multiple projects consuming one library:

```
projects
  library/
    src/
      lib/
        services/
          index.ts
    tsconfig.lib.json
  [projects...]
```

I want to use imports like

```
import {service} from "@services";
```

just within my library - but so far I'm getting a "Cannot find module `@services`" error.

I guess the path is incorrect - but I can't figure out how to fix that. Anyone got an idea?

edit: Used baseUrl: "src" - this works for building, but not when starting one of the projects with ng serve (due to the same error, "cannot find module"). (no aot flag used)

Thanks.

Comment: did you add baseurl bcs as per documentation [base url must be specified if "paths" is.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping)

Answer (score 2):

Refer to this tsconfig.json. Make sure this config file live at the same level of your src folder

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "paths": {
      "@app/*": [ "src/app/*" ],
      "@core/*": [ "src/app/core/*" ],
      "@environments/*": [ "src/environments/*" ],
      "@shared/*": [ "src/app/shared/*" ]
    },
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've spent the past couple of day struggling with the same issue and found a solution, for Angular 10 at least.

On `tsconfig.lib.json` you **must** define `baseUrl` like jitender mentioned.
Paths need to be relative to where `tsconfig.lib.json` is located.

Here are two options that worked for me:

```
"baseUrl": "./",
"paths": {
  "@services/*": ["src/lib/services/*"]
}
```

and

```
"baseUrl": "src/lib",
"paths": {
  "@services/*": ["services/*"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add baseurl bcs as per documentation [base url must be specified if "paths" is.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping)?

you will need to update path in tsconfig.json as well something like

```
"baseUrl":"./",
 "paths:"{
 "@services/*":["projects/ng-otp-input/src/lib/services"],
...
}
```

Also you will need to add same config in `tsconfig.lib.json` [For more info Refer to this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54982488/5621827)

Comment: Used `baseUrl: "src"` - this works for building, but not when starting one of the projects with `ng serve` (due to the same error, "cannot find module"). (no aot flag used)

Comment: @nehalist i have found something related to your query https://stackoverflow.com/a/54982488/5621827 hope this will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

add `"importHelpers": true,` to your ts config too.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

In Angulare 10.
We should add in `tsconfig.base.json`.

```
"paths": {
  "@services/*": ["src/lib/services/*"]
}
```

**Note: When you make changes then every time you should rebuild your project, Otherwise if use `@service` it will through error. because if faced multiple times.**